# Why is screen HEIGHT not taken into consideration while designing responsive layouts for mobile apps?

Tags: android, responsive-design, responsive

While creating responsive layouts for mobile apps, we take into account WIDTH of screen, and create layouts for different WIDTHS, but why don't we consider HEIGHT?

If 2 devices have a lot of difference in HEIGHT, my app in one device will look drastically different from the one in other device. Doesn't responsive layout mean that my app should look the same in devices of all widths and heights?

Comment: You are asking a design question: [What is the meaning of responsive design?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/q/50499/15773) rather than showing current & expected results along with code.

Answer (score 0):

The problem responsive design is trying to solve is that the vast majority of devices used to view web pages can't fit the entire page on screen at one time.

In response to this problem, the typical solution is to layout the content in one (or more) vertical column(s) (depending on device available width) so that the rest of the content (a.k.a. *"below the fold content"*) remains easily accessible by *scrolling vertically*.

Nobody says you can't create a website/app where the main scrolling direction is horizontal (which implicitly would mean your responsiveness intervals would be defined mainly around `max-height`). It's doable, although not without challenges, especially on mobile devices, as most mobile browsers are optimized for vertically scrollable web content, some of them implementing extra functionality based on this assumption (e.g: pull to refresh, various device/browser-specific menus typically sliding from sides, etc...). So, should you decide to create an app with horizontal scrolling, be prepared to come up with customized solutions for those devices, adapted to your atypical layout.

To answer your final question:

> *Doesn't responsive layout mean that my app should look the same in devices of all widths and heights?*

No, that's not what responsive design means, at all.

Responsive design implies the content *should adapt* (change form) based on viewport size. Technically, it means the opposite of what you understood: content should be presented ***differently*** on devices of various sizes and ratios, so that it remains *accessible*, *readable*, and *usable*, at all times.